# Kendo UI grid filter cell that contains an array

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to filter a specific column on a Kendo Grid that contains an array.

The grid configuration is

```
 var resultsGrid = this.kendoGrid({
        dataSource:{
            data:[],
            pageSize:20
        },
        sortable: {
            mode: "multiple",
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        filterable: {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                }
            }
        },
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        scrollable: false,
        columns: resultsColumns
    }).data("kendoGrid");
    return resultsGrid;
```

The columns configuration is

```
var resultsColumns = [
    {field: "keys", filterable: true, headerTemplate: function(){return Ec.translatedLabel("authorityEntryCode");}, template: '#for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){# #=keys[i].name# =  #=keys[i].value# <br> #}#'},
    {field: "state", filterable: true, headerTemplate: function(){return Ec.translatedLabel("state");}},
    {field: "startDate", filterable: false, headerTemplate: function(){return Ec.translatedLabel("startDate");}},
    {command: initGridCommands(), headerTemplate: function(){return Ec.translatedLabel("actions");}}
];
```

and I want to filter column with the field keys

The field keys is an array of object that contains name and value and I want to filter with the value.

For example
[Example of the Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkeAq.png)

So when the user adds a1 as in the screenshot to be filtered the first row.

Please if you have an answer on that it will help me alot, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is rather difficult to do in my opinion. The general process would require binding to the [filterMenuInit event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit), removing the contents of the default filter pop up with your own form and then performing the filtering manually on the specific fields you want. I'm not aware of a built in way to perform filtering on an array field. A hacky version overriding only what's required could be like:

```
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
          if (e.field == "keys") {
            var filterButton = e.container.find("button[type=submit]");
            var clearButton = e.container.find("button[type=reset]");
            var dataSource = jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

            //Get rid of default filter button...
            filterButton.remove();

            clearButton.parent().prepend("<button type='button' class='k-button k-primary'>Filter</button>");

            var filterText = e.container.find(".k-textbox");
            filterButton = e.container.find("button[type=button]");

            filterButton.click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();

               dataSource.filter([
                {
                    field: 'keys',
                    operator: function (items, filterValue) {
                      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if(items[i].value == filterText.val()) {
                          return true;
                        }
                      }
                      return false;
                    },
                    value: filterText.val()
                }
            ]);
            });

            clearButton.click(function() {
                dataSource.filter([]); //clear filters...
            });
          }
        },
```

This code is quick and dirty so I'd encourage you to read the docs concerning the [filterMenuInit event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit) and [data source filtering](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) to come up with a cleaner solution. [Here is a snippet as well.](http://dojo.telerik.com/AKIhu/5)

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution it helped me alot. I just made some modifications on the filter operator to understand the "contains" and the "eq" operation that I need. Also I had a problem when I was clicking on Filter button the dropdown was loosing its value so I made some modifications.  The snippet example with the modifications  http://dojo.telerik.com/ODiWa/3